# How to post date combined with hours with React JS?

Tags: reactjs, date

When I try to make a post request with React js to a make a reservation the time diminishes by two hours, while in the state it is exactly the time I wanted, meanwhile in the DB it is saved with two hours less. Example I try to save 11 o'clock instead saves 9 o'clock.

This is how format the date and time before passing it to the api call
`const booking_date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);`

Comment: Sounds like some timezone shifting/offset being applied by either the local machine or the backend.

Comment: Yes it happens before it is sent to the back end as I saw at parameters sent during the api call. How can I fix it? @DrewReese

Comment: That is probably not a problem at all but just a different representation of the same date. But you really need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, without a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's difficult to provide an accurate solution. Generally, though, when it comes to processing DateTime objects you want your entire system to be in agreement. In apps I've worked in (cruise industry) we treat all DateTime objects as UTC zone, meaning, no offsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timestamp to get a more accurate consistent date

```
const booking_date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute).getTime();
```

Then if you need an actual date string you can convert it back to a date using `new Date()`. This is likely a timezone issue so a timestamp would mitigate that, along with giving you the extra bonus of being able to send less data in the api call.

Alternatively, if you NEED a string date you can use:

```
new Date().toUTCString()
```

which will convert the date to a UTC string that is consistent across the world (it will give you the same value no matter your location) since it uses the standardised UTC timezone.

See more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: `toGMTString` has been deprecated, do not use it.

Comment: You should rather use `toISOString`. `toUTCString` has not been standardized until 2018 and parsing such a string might break in older (or non-compliant) browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). If you have a date string then convert it using moment.js before sending the post request or if you do not have any date string, you just need to pick the current date and time means then you can use as like below with the desired format you need. I'd recommend to always use UTC internally, and convert to a timezone only when displaying the date to the user

```
import moment from "moment";

let date = moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss')} // It will return 06-16-2020 08:54:00
```